# Can the correlation between uncertanties on variables be used to evaluate the correlation on variables?

Tags: correlation, uncertainty

Consider two variables $X$ and $Y$ correlated with a coefficient $\rho$. If associated to each measurement of $X$ and $Y$ we have independently estimated uncertainties $\epsilon_X$ and $\epsilon_Y$, respectively, can the correlation between these uncertainties be used to estimate $\rho$?

Comment: The short answer is no.  Consider a concrete example: using a device that tends to give results that are either both too high or too low, I measure your weight to the nearest kilogram and your height to the nearest centimeter.  *Based only on this information,* what can you tell us about how the heights and weights of people are related? Obviously nothing. Now maybe you have some particular variables in mind whose values might be so limited that measurement uncertainty conceivably provides a tiny bit of information about their joint distribution: what can you tell us about your variables?

Comment: That is what I feared. Thank you for the input.
I am not sure my case carries particular information, and I am more interested in the general answer (that you already provided).